# How to project values from a Gremlin traversal with nested and()/or() steps

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I have the graph model below which represents the sub-pattern I'd like to traverse or fetch. The nodes and their properties are shown below as well.

[image: graph]

The expected response to my query would look something like this:
where 's', 'c', 'aid', 'qid', 'p', 'r1', 'r2' are the nodes that make up the subpattern or subgraph.

```
[
  {
    "s": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "severity",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "severity": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "High"
          }
        ],
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "c": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "cve",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "cve_id": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "CVE-xxxx-xxxx"
          }
        ],
        "publishedOn": [
          {
            "id": "fc5dde4d-c027-4c19-9b16-b3314b2b10c6",
            "value": "xxx"
          }
        ],
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
"aid": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "aid",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "aid": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "xxxx-xxxx"
          }
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
"qid": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "qid",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "qid": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "xxxx-xxxx"
          }
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
"p": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "package",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "name": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "xxxxx"
          }
        ],
        "version": [
          {
            "id": "fc5dde4d-c027-4c19-9b16-b3314b2b10c6",
            "value": "xxx"
          }
        ],
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
"r1": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "release",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "source": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "xxxx-xxxx"
          }
        ],
        "status": [
          {
            "id": "fc5dde4d-c027-4c19-9b16-b3314b2b10c6",
            "value": "xxx"
          }
        ],
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
"r2": {
      "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4",
      "label": "release",
      "type": "vertex",
      "properties": {
        "source": [
          {
            "id": "a6a9e38f-0802-48b6-ac37-490f45e824e9",
            "value": "xxxx-xxxx"
          }
        ],
        "status": [
          {
            "id": "fc5dde4d-c027-4c19-9b16-b3314b2b10c6",
            "value": "xxx"
          }
        ],
        "pk": [
          {
            "id": "345fbdad-9c67-47bb-9f3b-cf50c8cdbee4|pk",
            "value": "pk"
          }
        ]
      }
    },

   {
    ....
    ....
   },

   {
    ....
    ..
   }
]
```

My question is how do I build my traversal query to achieve this end result?
What I have so far is this, but the project() step is not working as expected

```
g.V().hasLabel('cve').as('c').and(
    __.in('severity').as('s'),
    __.out('cve_to_aid').as('aid').and(
        __.out('has_qid').as('qid'),
        __.in('package_to_aid').as('p'),
        or(
            __.in('r1_to_aid').has('status', 'Patched').as('r1'),
            __.in('r2_to_aid').has('status', 'Patched').as('r2')
        )
    )
).project('c', 's', 'aid', 'qid', 'p', 'r1', 'r2').
by(('c').values('cve_id')).
by(('s').values('severity')).
by(('aid').values('aid')).
by(('qid').values('qid')).
by(('p').values()).
by(('r1').values()).
by(('r2').values()).
```

I am doing this on CosmosDB, so please only provide answers using supported steps found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to nest project() steps, e.g. on the TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1).as('x').project('x').by(
           select('x').project('id', 'label','properties').by(id).by(label).by(
             project('name').by(properties())
           )
         )
==>[x:[id:1,label:person,properties:[name:vp[name->marko]]]]
gremlin>
```

but then you end up coding your entire data model into your query.
In full TinkerPop you could turn your result into a [subGraph()](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) and write it to graphSon with the io() step. In Cosmos you can add the returned vertices to a [TinkerGraph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tinkergraph-gremlin) instance clientside and again use the [io() step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#io-step) to serialize the TinkerGraph to graphSon.